# Custom emoji reaction role

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

The reaction button works fine but the only problem it shows the ID of the custom emoji in embed message.

[image]

Here is the code:

```js
{name: 'reactionrole',
    description: "Sets up a reaction role message!",
    async execute(message, args, Discord, client) {
        const channel = '866637673937895457';
        const redTeamRole = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === "Red");
        const yellowTeamRole = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === "Yellow");
        const RandomTeamRole = message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name === "olddrawinlmaooo");
 
        const redTeamEmoji = '';
        const yellowTeamEmoji = '';
        const RandomTeamEmoji = '889108655344091156';
        

 
        let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setColor('#e42643')
            .setTitle('Choose a team to play on!')
            .setDescription('Choosing a team will allow you to interact with your teammates!\n\n'
                + `${redTeamEmoji} for yellow team\n`
                + `${yellowTeamEmoji} for blue team\n`
                + `${RandomTeamEmoji} for random team`);
 
        let messageEmbed = await message.channel.send(embed);
        messageEmbed.react(redTeamEmoji);
        messageEmbed.react(yellowTeamEmoji);
        messageEmbed.react(RandomTeamEmoji);
 
        client.on('messageReactionAdd', async (reaction, user) => {
            if (reaction.message.partial) await reaction.message.fetch();
            if (reaction.partial) await reaction.fetch();
            if (user.bot) return;
            if (!reaction.message.guild) return;
 
            if (reaction.message.channel.id == channel) {
                if (reaction.emoji.name === redTeamEmoji) {
                    await reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.add(redTeamRole);
                }
                if (reaction.emoji.name === yellowTeamEmoji) {
                    await reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.add(yellowTeamRole);
                }
                if (reaction.emoji.name === RandomTeamEmoji) {
                    await reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.add(RandomTeamRole);
                }
            } else {
                return;
            }
 
        });
 
        client.on('messageReactionRemove', async (reaction, user) => {
 
            if (reaction.message.partial) await reaction.message.fetch();
            if (reaction.partial) await reaction.fetch();
            if (user.bot) return;
            if (!reaction.message.guild) return;
 
 
            if (reaction.message.channel.id == channel) {
                if (reaction.emoji.name === redTeamEmoji) {
                    await reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.remove(redTeamRole);
                }
                if (reaction.emoji.name === yellowTeamEmoji) {
                    await reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.remove(yellowTeamRole);
                }
                if (reaction.emoji.name === RandomTeamEmoji) {
                    await reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.remove(RandomTeamRole);
                }
            } else {
                return;
            }
 
        });

    }

}  }
```

Comment: You have set `RandomTeamEmoji` as '889108655344091156' and then printing it. What is the expected output here?

Comment: You can use a ternary operator and use the emoji's name like 
``clicked === someid ? ":lemon:" : ":watermelon:"``

Answer (score 3):

Replace the ID with the emoji name AND the ID. It'll look something like this:

`<:yeah:735918408561852457>`

To get that easily, just put a \ in front of the emoji you want, and then send it in a channel, it'll give you that format.

Answer (score 2):

```js
const RandomTeamEmoji = '<:nameofemoji:889108655344091156>';
```

Instead of

```js
const RandomTeamEmoji = '889108655344091156';
```